# Difference between in and on.

Tags: prepositions

What is difference between prepositions **in** and **on** ?

> Cornwall is **in the south-east** of England.
>
> The Partridge Tree English School is near Norwich **on the east** coast of England.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **in** the south-east of England

means within the south-east region, surrounded by the border of the south-east region.

> **on** the east coast

generally means next to the water, a coast doesn't really have an area, otherwise you might say

> **in** the costal region

Comment: I would say that _on_ is used to mean _at or near a boundary_. So, for example, _on the east coast_ refers to the boundary between the ocean and the eastern shore, while _on the Peruvian border_ would refer to the border running between Peru and some adjacent nation, as in: _Huaquillas (Ecuador) is a city on the Peruvian border_.